# Use strtok() to divide the data recieved from socket into an array

Tags: c, sockets

```
#include<...>
char *buf;
void SetConfig(char *name);
.....

int main()
{
char text[1024];
recv(sock,&text,1024,0);

printf("%s\n",text); 

buf =(char*)calloc(1,1024);
SetConfig(name);
.....
}

void SetConfig(char *name)
{
int i=0;
char *Divdata;
char data[8];

Divdata= strtok(buf, "#");
while (Divdata != NULL){
data[i]=Divdata;
printf("%s\n",data[i++]);
Divdata = strtok(NULL, "#");
}
```

When I send data (127.0.0.1#255.255.255.0#test#test#test#test#test#test ) to this server I got the data and printf data exactly, but when the program run to printf("%s\n",data[i++]);

I show me a Segmentation fault.

Comment: Protip: *indent* (I stop reading questions as soon as I see the lack of or improper use of indents)

Comment: `char data[8];` --> `char *data[8];` and `SetConfig(name);` --> `SetConfig(text);` or `SetConfig(strcpy(buf, text));`

Comment: You seem to ignore the result from recv().  That is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value to data[i] & print only one character.

```
data[i]=*Divdata;
printf("%c\n",data[i++]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable all warnings in your compiler. Read all the compilation output, and act on the warnings.

You should be getting a warning for `printf("%s\n", data[i++]);`, since `data[i]` is a single character, which is the wrong data to provide to `%s`. It should be `%c` to print single characters.

Comment: Sorry,my data is not single characters. its like IP Adress

Comment: `data` may hold an IP address string, but `data[index]` returns a single character.  So it is wrong to pass a single character to `%s`, you have to use `%c` instead.